# How to run WebdriverIO tests with GitHub Actions?

Tags: selenium, github, webdriver, github-actions, webdriver-io

We are actually moving our repos to github and we want to use github actions for our pipelines, also our testautomation framework based on WebdriverIO. I'm completely new to github actions, I'm more an expert for Jenkins and Jenkins pipelines.

So, there is a really small github actions example on [WebdriverIO webpage](https://webdriver.io/docs/githubactions.html), but it is not really helpful for us/me. I try to execute only some tests on pushing some stuff to a branch. We are running that currently on "ubuntu-latest" image and I try to execute only some simple web tests, but it is not really easy possible. I tried the following ways at first:

1. Executing the tests using the chromedriver directly on ubuntu-latest image occurs an error:

   `ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.`
2. Using the wdio docker service with docker image "selenium/standalone-chrome-debug" produces also an error. If I re-run this job, then everything is fine. It is also a problem with a first run, bit the first run is the more interesting one ;):

   `ERROR wdio-docker-service: Failed to run container: request to http://localhost:4444/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444`

Maybe you have some experiences, recommendations or examples for me to solve that issue? What is the best way to execute WebdriverIO tests via GitHub actions?

This is my github action workflow yaml:

```
name: Testautomation Example

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup
        run: npm install
      - name: Test
        # 1. issue with chromedriver
        #run: ENV_PATH=environment/QS npm run clear-test -- "wdio-configs/wdio.conf.chrome.chromedriver.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression=@example"
        # 2. issue with wdio docker service
        run: ENV_PATH=environment/QS npm run clear-test -- "wdio-configs/wdio.conf.chrome.docker.debug.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression=@example"
      - name: Upload Test Reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: reports
          path: tests/reports/
      - name: Upload Logs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: logs
          path: log/
```

Comment: You don't need to run docker in github pipeline. It's running already in a docker context. I have an example running WebdriverIO tests in pipeline https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issues and this is an example github workflow for the github actions:

```
name: Multiple Environments Example

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  e2e-test-on-ubuntu-with-local-chrome:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #runs-on: macos-latest
    #runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup
        run: npm install
      - name: Test
        run: npm run clear-test -- "wdio-configs/wdio.conf.chrome.chromedriver.headless.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression=@myTests"
        env:
          ENV_PATH: environment/QS
      - name: Upload Test Reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: reports
          path: tests/reports/
      - name: Upload Logs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: logs
          path: log/
```