# GitHub actions unable to run wdio test

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions

I've been trying to get github actions to do the CI part of this particular test that has been created however, I also encounter a similar error when running the test. The test works locally, so that's great. When it's solely being ran with GitHub actions, it doesn't.

I first see a warning:

```
 WARN @wdio/mocha-framework: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
```

which eventually becomes an error on the test:

```
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
```

What else do I need to do in GitHub actions to get this to run the test and pass as it should?
The yml file has been set up to do the following:

```
name: CI
on: [push, pull_request]
env:
  SAUCE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SAUCE_USERNAME }}
  SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY }}
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Install Chromium
          run: sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
        - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
          with:
            node-version: 18
        - name: Install
          run: npm install
        - name: Test
          run: npx wdio wdio.git.js
        - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          if: failure()
          with:
            name: logs
            path: logs
```

You can also see the repo here: https://github.com/saucechaffe/sauceonsauceoff

I've attempted to change the yml file to configure different things, I've read that it isn't necessary to build chrome on the ubuntu machine but on some hands it is so I've left it in there for now. I've also attempted this: [How to run WebdriverIO tests with GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205928/how-to-run-webdriverio-tests-with-github-actions) but just keep getting stuck in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by removing a line of code that required chrome webdriver as it was causing the error and wasn't needed/being used.